# Best way for showing a horizontal progress bar with percentage during a file upload?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

I am new to android and trying one simple image uploading application. I am able to do all uploading with asynctask and its working fine. I am currently showing simple progress dialogue and all is fine but I want show percentage with progress bar. I am using asynctask for upload and not getting idea to show percentage. anyone can please help me for do it?

My code is like below

```
public void UploadImageToServer(){

    FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

    byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

    class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();


            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"Image is Uploading","Please Wait",false,false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

            super.onPostExecute(string1);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

            HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

            HashMapParams.put(ImageTag, GetImageNameFromEditText);

            HashMapParams.put(ImageName, ConvertImage);

            String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest(URL, HashMapParams);

            return FinalData;
        }
    }
    AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
    AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
}

public class ImageProcessClass{

    public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);

            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

            bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();

            RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

            if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String RC2;

                while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                    stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
            if (check)
                check = false;
            else
                stringBuilder.append("&");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilder.append("=");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s a built-in mechanism for progress updates in `AsyncTask`. All you need to do to access it, is override `onProgressUpdate` within the `AsyncTask`. It gets the progress as a parameter that you can use to update the UI. Considering that the `AsyncTask` runs in a background thread and you need to update the UI thread with the progress, you can call `publishProgress` from your `doInBackground` which makes the progress update run on the UI thread.

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
    progressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
 }
```

Comment: What is String progress and from where I can get value of it? Can You please example with my code? Thanks!

Comment: @rajrathod This is the parameter that goes into the publishProgress() method that you call from the doInBackground. It doesn't have to be a String, it can be an integer that you define, I just copied it from one of my projects were I had it as a String. I'll check the logic in your code and see If I can be more specific

Comment: It will be very helpful for me. Thanks!